# Reply to 2 different requests using MockServer

Tags: mocking

I am using mock server to simulate an external server. However, the first url is correctly emulated but not the second one:

```
mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);

mockServerClient = new MockServerClient("localhost", 1080);
mockServerClient
        .when(
                request()
                        .withMethod("GET")
                        .withPath("/myurl1/"),
                exactly(1)
        )
        .respond(
                response()
                        .withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody("OK")
        );

mockServerClient
        .when(
                request()
                        .withMethod("GET")
                        .withPath("/myurl2/"),
                unlimited()
        )
        .respond(
                response()
                        .withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody("true")
        );
```

Any idea on how to do it? I did not found any examples online.

Comment: hm, what static imports do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to forward and see what happens. It should go something like this:

```
mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);

    mockServerClient = new MockServerClient("localhost", 1080);
    mockServerClient
            .when(
                    request()
                            .withMethod("GET")
                            .withPath("/myurl1/"),
                    exactly(1)
            )
            .respond(
                    response()
                            .withStatusCode(200)
                            .withBody("OK")
            );
            .forward(
                    forward()
                            .withHost("/myurl12")
                            .withPort(80)
                            .withScheme(HTTP)
            );
```